# Find the top matches comparing table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, intersect

I have a database with up to 400 tables mixed from different sources. I need to group those tables in an excel file by column similarity (considering that tables have 0, 1, 2, or all columns with the same name). The challenge is as the example follows:

```
fac.table_1 have columns C1, C2, C3, C4 and C5
dim.table_2 has columns C1, C3, and C5
stg.table_3 has columns C1, C6, and C7
stg.table_4 has columns C2, and C99
```

...

The expected result should be:

```
sch_name | table_name | ncols | nmatches
  dim    |   table_2  |   3   |   3
  stg    |   table_3  |   3   |   1
  stg    |   table_4  |   2   |   1
```

I think the way is to use something like this code together with COUNT or INTERSECT, inserting in WHERE the table name that I want to compare with others:

```
    SELECT
       schemas.name sch_nm,
       tables.name tb_nm,
       columns.name col_nm
    FROM sys.tables
       LEFT JOIN sys.columns ON tables.object_id = columns.object_id
       LEFT JOIN sys.schemas ON tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id
```

Comment: Could  you provide some sample data from your expect result?

Comment: D-Shih, the expected result is the count how much columns are in each table and how much of that are equal the parameter table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to count the number of columns which the column name exists in another table ?

```
select sch_name, tbl_name, 
       ncols      = count(*), 
       nmatches   = sum(case when col_cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end),
       percentage = sum(case when col_cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*) 
from
(
    select sch_name = s.name, 
           tbl_name = t.name,
           col_name = c.name,
           col_cnt  = count(c.name) over(partition by c.name)
    from   sys.schemas s
           inner join sys.tables t  on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
           inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
    where  t.name in ('table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4')
) c       
where tbl_name not in ('table1')
group by sch_name, tbl_name
order by c.tbl_name;
```

Result :

| sch_name | tbl_name | ncols | nmatches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fac | table_1 | 5 | 4 |
| dim | table_2 | 3 | 3 |
| stg | table_3 | 3 | 1 |
| stg | table_4 | 2 | 1 |

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=afd732c9b4f368210f1bf57b82a8fe63)

Comment: But I want to specify which table will be compared, for example: I need to know how much columns from table_1 existis in table_2, and in table_3, etc. After the analysis, I will change that parameter for another column, so, I will compare how much columns from table_2 existis in table_3, and in table_4, etc.

Comment: add a `WHERE` condition to the query

Comment: Using this clause, the result brings to me only the table that I specified in the ´WHERE´, not the comparison between all the other tables.

Comment: Maybe I am not knowing the correct place to insert the WHERE condition.

Comment: add `WHERE` in the outer query if you want to filter the final result. Add it in the inner query if you want to limit those tables in comparisons. Edited the query to illustrate how to exclude `table1` from final result but it is included in the comparisons

Comment: Awesome! That worked!!!! I can't believe it. If you permit, I have about 400 tables to compare like this. Is it possible to don't insert manually the tables at the inner query, but only change the parameter in the WHERE condition?

Comment: I would like to insert a percentage column based on nmatches / ncols. Is that possibel?

Comment: Edited query added `percentage`. Don't quite understand your situation of `400` tables. If you are comparing for all tables in the database, you don't need the `where` clause in the inner query.